# C++ Function Calling Assembly Module

Tags: c++, masm, name-decoration

I want to write a customized module in assembly and have my C++ functions invoke it.  Instead of starting from scratch I would like to write the "draft" in C and let the compiler generates a blue print assembly source i.e.the listing file generated by the /FA compiler option.

However, I found that all the procedure names generated are already in decorated form.  Furthermore, the MASM will carry out its own name decoration again. So if I assemble my version without undecorating the compiler generated procedure name manually first I would get a linker error since the function names would not be matching.

Is possible to prevent this type of duplicated name decoration?

Comment: Question really has nothing to do with assembly?

Comment: Don't forget most compilers support inline assembly. This may get you where you need to go without worrying about interfacing between the C++ and assembler

Comment: No, inline assembly is no longer a good option unless there is no concern about upgrading it to x64. x64 doesn't support inline assembly and is causing much trouble to old codes.

Comment: The x64 compiler doesn't support inline assembly because it is generally not needed, and it interferes with optimizing the rest of the code. Are you sure you really can do better than the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the function `extern "C"` should result in the generated assembler showing the name you should use in assembler.  Just don't forget to make it `extern "C"` in the header which declares it to C++ later.

Comment: I tried the extern "C". And as another reply already pointed out, the generated names only got a leading _. But using that name directly won't help as the MASM tries to do its own decoration again. I want to avoid manually editing the generated names.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MASM, so I can't say, but if there's no way it can be made to generate the name you get with `extern "C"`, then you've got a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your function as `extern "C"`. That way, it will at most get an underscore before the name:

```
extern "C"{
  void foo(int bla){
  }
}
```

Will become

```
_foo
```